# Woocommerce get count of products by category type across all shop pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to check how many products of a particular product category the client has added to their basket at each iteration (ie added 1 or several, or removed 1 or several). I want to pass this to the Front End and store in localStorage so I can set cookies with it. And I need to be able to check this whenever it changes.

Initially I tried to do this mapping to a click function for the add to cart button. This won't work as you can click but the add to cart might be unsuccessful (not enough stock, price too low, as I am trying to implement a pay what you want component).

I've found various ways to try and list all product categories, or retrieve the current item, but cannot find exactly how to do what I want.

Inside my cart object I first tried:

```php
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in hidden">' . _n( '', '', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ), '</span>' );
```

But this works only seems to work on product pages.

Then this which looked promising:

```php
wp_list_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'title_li'  => '') );
```

This returns all product categories

And this:

```php
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $cart_item['product_id'] );
```

This seems to retrieve the first (or only one) product category, and it does not return anything  on the cart page.

Basically I am looking for

product category: `product_a`, count: `2`

Or something very similar to this. My goal is to limit the number of products a user can purchase in one transaction but only for one product category. IE they can purchase unlimited products if not in the restricted category.

Hope this makes sense.

**UPDATE**

I found [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/checking-woocommerce-cart-contains-product-category/) which is *almost* working

```
<?php
    // holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category
    $category_checks = array();

    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_in_cat = false;

        // replace 'membership' with your category's slug
        if ( has_term( 'instant-print', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $product_in_cat = true;
        }

        array_push( $category_checks, $product_in_cat );
    }

    // if all items are in this category, do something
    if ( ! in_array( false, $category_checks, true ) ) {
        echo 'items in category' . count($category_checks);
    } else {
        echo 'No items in category' . count($category_checks);
    }
?>
```

The only issue is it seems the length of the array is for all products in the cart rather than the ones that match my product category 'instant-print'.

Comment: Does (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382885/woocommerce-customize-email-with-item-total-count/382887#382887) help? Which will output the number of items and categories in the cart.

Comment: @Ruvee Thanks, I am already using that in the cart counter, but that just gets the total number of products, I need to know the total number of products by product category (because I want some product types to have a limit)

Comment: It's close though, If I could use it with a map or filter function (I know js much better so php is a bit of an unknown quantity for me)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have something that is working and it was relatively straightforward.

I am now using:

```
<?php
    // holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category
    $category_checks = array();

    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_in_cat = false;

        // replace 'membership' with your category's slug
        if ( has_term( 'instant-print', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $product_in_cat = true;
        }

        array_push( $category_checks, $product_in_cat );
    }

   $filtered_array = count(array_filter($category_checks));
   echo '<span class="limited-product-count hidden">' . $filtered_array . '</span>'

?>
```